# Assigning static IP address using nmcli

Tags: networking, fedora, nmcli

So I'm trying to give a VM a static IP address, this case has been particularly stubborn.

The VM is running on a ESXi cluster with its own public IP range.

I had it (sorta) working with an IPv4 address, except it would be reassigned every boot, now after fiddling with nmcli I can't get any IPv4 address assigned to it.

The interface is `ens32` and I've changed `ipv4.addresses` to `XXX.XXX.120.44/24` (want it to have address `120.44`), gateway to `XXX.XXX.120.1` and set it to manual.

Does anyone have any insights to why this isn't working? all the online guides are for the older network service not NetworkManager.

Comment: So it has to be over network manager at all costs?

Comment: Or is there DHCP available? That would push the complexity off onto the DHCP server, and only require that the node uses DHCP.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've changed the title to be more generic.

Comment: @phk fedora 23 doesn't like you enabling network and thus you can't use the older configuration system

Comment: Do you not have nmtui?

Comment: this is a minimal install of Fed23 for an appliance that has no internet access

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
# nmcli con add con-name "static-ens32" ifname ens32 type ethernet ip4 xxx.xxx.120.44/24 gw4 xxx.xxx.120.1
# nmcli con mod "static-ens32" ipv4.dns "xxx.xxx.120.1,8.8.8.8"
# nmcli con up "static-ens32" iface ens32
```

Next, find the other connections and delete them. For example:

```
# nmcli con show
NAME         UUID                 TYPE           DEVICE
ens32        ff9804db5-........   802-3-ethernet --
static-ens32 a4b59cb4a-........   802-3-ethernet ens32
# nmcli con del ens32
```

On the next reboot, you should pick up the `static-ens32` connection, as it is the only one available.

Comment: I am trying to do this from the raw starting point of a fresh installation, which requires a somewhat different sequence of commands.  Are you willing to show how to do this from scratch with a fresh installation of CentOS 7?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349607/nmcli-commands-for-static-ip-networking-in-centos-7

Comment: Change "iface" by "ifname" when starting the connection again.

Answer (score 0):

An individual IPv4 address is /32. /24 designates a network, which in this case would be XXX.XXX.120.[0-255]. Try changing the `ipv4.address` entry to `XXX.XXX.120.44/32` and see what happens. If that doesn't work, I have to then ask the same question asked in comments - is NetworkManager a requirement, or can we configure the address using other means?

Comment: `nmcli` wants the IP address with the subnet mask in CIDR notation.

Comment: I've played around with the CIDR notation with the /24 /16 and /32 neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing /32(single) to /24(network) fixed my problem with ipv4.addresses assigning range and first ip address.

I think "manual" could be a problem in your case. Manual may tell nm to not manage at all, or not handle dhcp. Have you tried "shared", and then ipv4.addresses rather than ipv4.address1? Or, if manual, then ipv4.address1 might be correct instead of ipv4.addresses.

Have you looked in /var/log/syslog? dnsmasq said in mine that 32 was too small, and nmcli reported back "too small" in the error output.