# Multiple NetworkManager connection profiles for the same ethernet interface not always work correctly

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, ethernet, nmcli

I'm using 3 NetworkManager connection profiles in a Linux distribution and all the connection profiles refer to the same ethernet interface: `enp3s0`. I'm using these connections to manage:

- the default static IP configuration
- set a new static IP configuration
- request a DHCP address

In the rest of the question I'll use the term **connection** to mean the term **connection profile**.

To change Ethernet configuration I change the priority of the connection, so if I would like to enable the default static IP configuration I set a priority for that greater than static IP configuration and DHCP configuration.
Read the paragraph **"Set properties of the 3 connections"** in the continuation of the question to get details about setting of priority of a connection.

#### The question

If I create connections at boot by a bash script started by a `systemd` service all works correctly, but if I execute the bash script after the boot has finished, the IP configuration is not correctly managed by NetworkManager and its connection profiles.
Go to the paragraph **"The problem"** at the end of the question to get a detailed description of the error.

The rest of the question give all details needed to understand the problem.
**I apologize for the length of the question but there is a lot of information needed.**

---

#### Creation of 3 NetworkManager connection profiles

To create the connections I'm using the command `nmcli` as showed below:

```
# for default static
nmcli c add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_default_ipstatic
# for ethernet_ipstatic
nmcli c add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_ipstatic
# for ethernet_dhcp
nmcli c add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_dhcp
```

After the execution of previous commands in the path `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, there will be present 3 files called:

- `ethernet_default_ipstatic.nmconnection`
- `ethernet_ipstatic.nmconnection`
- `ethernet_dhcp.nmconnection`

#### Set properties of the 3 connections

Previous commands create 3 connections with default properties, so after creating them it is necessary to set their properties. For this goal I still used the command `nmcli` as showed below.

For the `ethernet_default_ipstatic` set the following properties for the connection:

```
nmcli con mod ethernet_default_ipstatic ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.1/24 ipv6.method disabled
```

Previous command set the following properties for the connection:

- ipv4.method = manual (this set IP Static and not DHCP)
- ip address 192.168.1.1, netmask 255.255.255.0 (no gateway)
- IPV6 disabled
- the autoconnection propriety remains to default yes
- the priority property remains to **default 0**

For the `ethernet_ipstatic` the properties are:

```
nmcli con mod ethernet_ipstatic ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.1/24 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.100 ipv4.may-fail no ipv6.method disabled connection.autoconnect no connection.autoconnect-priority -1
```

Previous command set the following properties for the connection:

- ipv4.method = manual (this set IP Static and not DHCP)
- ip address 192.168.1.1, netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.1.100
- IPV6 disabled, autoconnection no, **priority -1**

For the `ethernet_dhcp` the properties are:

```
nmcli con mod ethernet_dhcp ipv4.method auto ipv4.addresses '' ipv4.gateway '' ipv4.may-fail no ipv4.dhcp-timeout 20 ipv6.method disabled connection.autoconnect no connection.autoconnect-priority -1 connection.autoconnect-retries 3
```

Previous command set the following properties for the connection:

- ipv4.method = auto (this set DHCP and not Static IP Address)
- ip address '', gateway ''
- IPV6 disabled, autoconnection no, **priority -1**

#### Default configuration

By previous commands the connection `ethernet_default_ipstatic` has a priority > than others so the ethernet interface `enp3s0` is configured with an IP static `192.168.1.1/24`.

#### Execution of `nmcli` commands by a service

All work correctly If I execute previous `nmcli` commands at boot by the following service (`my_custom_nm_service.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Init NetworkManager Ethernet Connections
Requires=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/<username>/script_services/init_connections.sh
User=<username>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where `init_connections.sh` executes previous `nmcli` commands.

**Note.** In the unit file note the presence of the opsions:

- Requires=NetworkManager.service
- After=NetworkManager.service
- Before=network.target

#### The problem

If after the boot has finished I remove all connections, by the command `nmcli con del`, and I execute the script `init_connections.sh` I obtain a unpredictable IP configuration for the system.
The typical misconfiguration that occurs is as follows:

- the active connection (showed by `nmcli con` command) is `ethernet_default_ipstatic` so the system should have the static IP address `192.168.1.1/24`
- but the system has obtained an IP address by the DHCP server

When the script `init_connections.sh` is executed by the service, it is executed **before network.target**, but honestly I don't know if this difference could be important to understand the problem or not.

Comment: Instead of calling `init_connections.sh`, why not run `systemctl restart my_custom_nm_service`? You can then really compare with boot time since systemd will take care of the dependencies. Or just `systemctl restart NetworkManager`? since you are doing a `nmcli con del`.

Comment: @xhienne My goal is not use the service `my_custom_nm_service` and create connections by a Python program which call `nmcli` commands as in the script `init_connections.sh`.

Comment: @xhienne I have tried to call `systemctl restart NetworkManager` after deleting connections but this not solves the problem; the same if I execute `systemctl restart NetworkManager` after creating the connections my system get the DHCP address and not IP Static default address.

Comment: @xhienne Thanks. Your hints have helped me to find the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Congrats for the quality of both your question and your answer. Don't forget to accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: why do you recreate the profiles on each boot? Usually, a profile is persisted to disk and you only create it once. Upon next boot, autoconnect and `connection.autoconnect-priority` takes care that the desired profile activates automatically.

If you already have a script that is aware and generates 3 profiles, you can explicilty activate the one you want (`nmcli connection up`). At that point, there is no need to rely on autoconnect.

Comment: Thank you @thaller. I agree with you it is not necessary to recreate the connection on each boot. But I don't do this but only sometimes in a specific situation which I have not explained because is not important for the question. This can be unsterstand by the first sentence of the paragraph **The problem**:  *If after the boot has finished I remove all connections...*, only if I remove all connections after the boot, but I don't remove the connection after each boot. I hope now is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem: to set correctly the default configuration I need to execute the `nmcli con up` command as showed below:

```
nmcli con up "ethernet_default_ipstatic" iface enp3s0
```

as also indicated in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/assigning-static-ip-address-using-nmcli/290949#290949).

**Note.** In this moment for me is not important to know why the execution of the script `init_connections.sh` works well at boot by the service `my_custom_nm_service.service`. My real interest is to make working the script at the end of the boot process.

---

For completeness I write the steps of my test.

##### 1) remove the service

I have disabled the service `my_custom_nm_service.service` which started the execution of the script `init_connections.sh`

##### 2) delete all connections

After the boot has finished I have deleted all the connection by the following script (`delete_connections.sh`):

```
nmcli c del ethernet_default_ipstatic
nmcli c del ethernet_ipstatic
nmcli c del ethernet_dhcp
```

##### 3) creation of the 3 connections: the malfunction appears

Execute the script `init_connections.sh`:

```
nmcli con add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_default_ipstatic
nmcli con mod ethernet_default_ipstatic ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.1/24 ipv6.method disabled
nmcli con add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_ipstatic
nmcli con mod ethernet_ipstatic ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.1/24 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.100 ipv4.may-fail no ipv6.method disabled connection.autoconnect no connection.autoconnect-priority -1
nmcli con add ifname enp3s0 type ethernet con-name ethernet_dhcp
nmcli con mod ethernet_dhcp ipv4.method auto ipv4.addresses '' ipv4.gateway '' ipv4.may-fail no ipv4.dhcp-timeout 20 ipv6.method disabled connection.autoconnect no connection.autoconnect-priority -1 connection.autoconnect-retries 3
```

After the execution of the script, my Linux system, presents the problem described in the question that is:

- `nmcli con` command tells that the active connection is `ethernet_default_ipstatic` (because it has the greater priority)
- the IP address has been assigned by the DHCP Server

##### 4) solution: execute `nmcli con up`

The solution is execute the command:

```
nmcli con up "ethernet_default_ipstatic" iface enp3s0
```

and after that the interface `enp3s0` has the default IP address